# Entity framework (core), save incomplete model containing required fields

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-core

Using : dotnet core 1.1, entity framework code first, sql server.

Is there any elegant way to enable a user working on a large form, represented by a complexe model (40+ tables/C# objects), having multiple "required" fields, to save it's work temporarily and come back to complete it afterward?

Let's say I have this model :

```
[Table("IdentificationInfo", Schema = "Meta")]
public class IdentificationInfo : PocoBase
{ 
    [...]
    public int MetaDataId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MetaDataId")]
    public virtual MetaData MetaData { get; set; }

    public int ProgressId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProgressId")]
    public Progress Progress { get; set; }

    public virtual MaintenanceInfo MaintenanceInfo { get; set; }

    public int PresentationFormId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PresentationFormId")]
    public PresentationForm PresentationForm { get; set; }

    private string _abstract;
    [Required]
    public string Abstract
    {
        get { return _abstract; }
        set { SetFieldValue(ref _abstract, value, "Abstract"); }
    }
    [...]
}

[Table("PresentationForm", Schema = "Meta")]
public class PresentationForm : PocoEnumeration
{
    [...] 
}
```

The user starts to fill everything (in a big form with multiples tabs or really long page!), but needs to stop and save the progress without having the time to save to fill the `PresentationForm` part, nor the `abstract`. Normally, in the `database`, those fields are **not null**, so it would fail when we try to save the model. Similarly, it would also fail with EF validation in the UI.

What would be nice is using the `Progress` property and disable EF model validation `(model.isValid())`, and also enable `database insert` even if the fields are **null** (it is not possible to put **default** values in those not nullable fields as they are often foreign keys to enum like table).

For the model validation part, I know we can make some custom validator, with custom annotation such as `[RequiredIf("FieldName","Value","Message")]`. I'm really curious about some method to do something similar in the `database`?

Would the easy way to do that be to save the model as `JSON` in a temporary table as long as the progress status is not completed, retrieve it when needed for edition directly from the `JSON`, and save it to the `database` only when the status is completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support (elegantly) what you ask you should design it that way.
One table with it's required columns should be minimum segment that have to be inputted before any save. Should make segment optimal size.
You could set all fields to allow null but that would be very BAD design, so I would not consider that option at all.

Now if your input consist of several logical parts, and on form they could be different tabs so each tab is in one table in Db and main table have FKs of others tables.
That *FK* could be *Nullable*, and it would enable you to finish say first 2 tabs, Save it, and leave rest for after. So you will know that those FK column that have values are finished(and maybe could be edited still), while others are yet to be inserted. You can also have column *Status:Draft/Active/...*

What's more this design would allow you to have configurable tabs, so for example based on some chosen selection on main input you could chose what tables can be inputted, and which not and to *enable/disable* appropriate tabs.

If however you don't want *FKs* nullable than solution would be some temporary storage, one option being *JSON* in one string column, as you have mentioned your self. But I see no issues with nullable *FKs* in this case.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, we also though about making groups of discreete inputs, but the process of filling the form is far from straightforward, and the information needed is not consistently available in a timely fashion.